# How to generate ODF charts with Perl

Tags: perl, odf, opendocument

How to create Open Document Format spreadsheet *with charts* using Perl?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [`ODF::lpOD`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?ODF::lpOD)? The page for [`ODF::lpOD::StructuredContainer`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?ODF::lpOD::StructuredContainer#Draw_pages) says it gives access to "draw pages"

> This manual page is related to the sections, item lists, *draw pages*, frames, and drawing shapes.

If you're not talking about the generalized format, and your target is specifically [OpenOffice.org](http://openoffice.org/) you want to get right down to the bottom of it you could use [`OpenOffice::UNO`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?OpenOffice::UNO).

If nothing else, because charts exist in the XML, you can probably manipulate the XML in the document.

Comment: So far, I have tried only `OpenOffice::OODoc`. I'll give `ODF::lpOD` a try.

Comment: Update: first paragraph of linked section states: "They shouldn't appear in text or spreadsheet documents", unfortunately.

Comment: @el.pescado, Yeah it looks like Charts are a TODO for the main project as well: http://docs.lpod-project.org/level1-graphic-content.html#charts-todo

Answer (score 1):

I use [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/) to make Excel spreadsheets with charts and I open the documents just fine in Open Office, on Linux or Windows.

You can also now use [Excel::Writer::XLSX](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Excel-Writer-XLSX/)